# How to define own func argument inside itertools.accumulate?

Tags: python, function, iteration, python-itertools

The usage of itertools.accumulate is as follows:

```
itertools.accumulate(iterable[, func, *, initial=None])
```

For example

```
list(itertools.accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13],operator.sub))
# [0, -7, -26, -39]
```

Where I used subtraction operator as `func` argument.

How to define my own `func` argument?

I want it similar to `operator.sub` but instead of subtracting second item from first item I need to subtract first item from second item.

The output `[0, -7, -26, -39]` was produced as follows:

```
[0, (0) - (7), (0 - 7) - (19), ((0 - 7) - (19)) - (13)] == [0, -7, -26, -39]
```

I want it:

```
[0, (7) - (0), (19) - (7 - 0), (13) - ((19) - (7 - 0))] == [0, 7, 12, 1]`
```

It is same as with `operator.sub` just the order of arguments inside subtraction is swapped. Or other way said - if `operator.sub` is doing `x1-x2` I want it to do `x2-x1` at each iteration step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everthing is an object in python, and can be passed around, including functions. `func` can be any callable, which includes lambdas, functions, methods, and arbitrary objects whose class has a `__call__` method.

Here are some examples of these options:

1. A `lambda` is a special one-expression function that is is very easy to define. It's handy because you can use it anonymously inline:

   ```
    accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], lambda a, b: b - a)
   ```

   Since everything is an object, the lambda doesn't have to be anonymous:

   ```
    func = lambda a, b: b - a
    accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], func)
   ```
2. Functions are probably the most ubiquitous callable. You make a function with the `def` statement:

   ```
    def func(a, b):
        return b - a
    accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], func)
   ```

   Notice that this looks a lot like the `lambda` when you assign it to a name. Lambdas and functions that return a single expression behave almost exactly the same in most regards.

   You can use a built-in function as well:

   ```
    accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], operator.rsub)
   ```

   Even most class methods exist as functions in the class object. If you have a uniform list, e.g., all `int`s, you can take advantage of this:

   ```
    accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], int.__rsub__)
   ```

   This works because `int.__rsub__` is a function accepting two arguments, which lives in the class `int`. When you do `(3).__rsub__(4)`, you bind that function to an instance, which turns it into a method with just one explicit argument.
3. A more esoteric type of callable is an instance of a class with a `__call__` method:

   ```
    class Subtractor:
        def __call__(self, a, b):
            return b - a
    accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], Subtractor())
   ```

   Notice the parentheses in `Subtractor()`. They create a new instance, which is callable because the class defines `__call__`.
4. A special case of function-like objects are `staticmethod` and `classmethod` objects. They are not strictly functions, but wrap function objects inside a class. If you have a utility class, the `@staticmethod` decorator could be applied to a function that does not rely on the class or instance state:

   ```
    class Subtractor:
        @staticmethod
        def func1(a, b):
            return b - a
        @classmethod
        def func2(cls, a, b):
            return b - a

    accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], Subtractor.func1)
    accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], Subtractor().func2)
   ```

   `func1` behaves like a normal function. In fact, it won't bind to an instance at all: you can also do `accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], Subtractor().func1)`. `func2`, however, must be bound, but to the class and not the instance. You could call `accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], Subtractor.func2)` as well.

Comment: `func2` is always bound to the class, you could also do `Subtractor.func2`, so your last sentence is misleading. Otherwise great answer!

Comment: @Jasmijn. You're right. Fixed. I was thinking about what happens with inheritance, but that's pretty irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function with two arguments, that returns the result of subtracting the first from the second:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def my_sub(a, b):
  return b - a

print(list(accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], my_sub)))
```

Output:

```
[0, 7, 12, 1]
```

Or you could use a `lambda`:

```
list(accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], lambda a, b : b - a))
```

Comment: Is this the simplest possible way? Something like `-operator.sub` will not work?

Comment: This is a good place to use a `lambda`, but I don't think _being in a hurry_ is a good argument for anything ;)

Comment: Ohh... I prefer the way using `lambda`. Thank you.

Comment: @zvone: Is there anything wrong with using `lambda`? Is it slower or something?

Comment: @azerbajdzan you can't use `-operator.sub`, `operator.sub` is a function, you can't make a function negative, you can build your function in terms of `operator.sub`, like so, for instance: `lambda a, b : -operator.sub(a, b)`.

Comment: To answer azerbajdzan's question.  No.  That won't work.  But I also like to say that Python doesn't bite.  If uncertain, try it!  See what happens.